# SQL right join, force return only one value from right hand side

Tags: sql, oracle10g

```
table 1
---
id , name

table2
---
id , activity, datefield
```

table1 'right join' table2 will return more than 1 results from right table (table2) . how to make it return only "1" result from table2 with the highest date

Comment: Need more context: Are you just interested in the max Date per some criteria form Table2, or a bunch of columns from table 2?

Comment: table1 join with table2, table3,table4..etc .. i want to get one row from table2, but then entire query , i want to return bunch of columns

Answer (score 3):

You write poor information about your problem, But I'll try to make an example to help you.

You have a table "A" and a table "B" and you need to fetch the "**top**" date of table "B" that is related with table "A"

*Example tables:*

```
Table A:
 AID| NAME
----|-----
  1 |  Foo
  2 |  Bar

Table B:

BID | AID | DateField
----| ----| ----
 1  |   1 | 2000-01-01
 2  |   1 | 2000-01-02
 3  |   2 | 2000-01-01
```

*If you do this sql:*

```
SELECT * FROM A RIGHT JOIN B ON B.ID = A.ID
```

You get all information of A and B that is related by ID (that in this theoretical case is the field that is common for both tables to link the relation)

```
A.AID | A.NAME | B.BID | B.AID | B.DateField
------|--------|-------|-------|--------------
  1   |   Foo  |   1   |   1   |   2000-01-01
  1   |   Foo  |   2   |   1   |   2000-01-02
  2   |   Bar  |   3   |   2   |   2000-01-01
```

But you require only the last date for each element of the Table A (the top date of B)

Next if you need to get only the top DATE you need to group your query by the B.AID and fetch only the top date

```
SELECT 
      B.AID, First(A.NAME), MAX(B.DateField) 
FROM 
      A RIGHT JOIN B ON B.ID = A.ID 
GROUP BY 
      B.AID
```

*And The result of this operation is:*

```
B.AID | A.NAME | B.DateField
------|--------|--------------
  1   |   Foo  |  2000-01-02
  2   |   Bar  |  2000-01-01
```

In this result I removed some fields that are duplicated (like A.AID and B.AID that is the relationship between the two tables) or are not required.

- Tip: this also works if you have more tables into the sql. The sql "makes" the query and next applies a grouping for using the B to limit the repetitions of B to the top date.

Answer (score 2):

right join table2 on on table1.id to to select id, max = max(date) from table2

Comment: my table 1 is join to many other tables beside tabl2, so i cannot use query like you suggstion as that will return 1 result.  see my updated question. i want table2 return only the latest "datefield"

Answer (score 1):

**Analytics!**

Test data:

```
create table t1
  (id        number       primary key,
   name      varchar2(20) not null
  );

create table t2
  (id        number not null, 
   activity  varchar2(20) not null,
   datefield date not null
  );

insert into t1 values (1, 'foo');
insert into t1 values (2, 'bar');
insert into t1 values (3, 'baz');

insert into t2 values (1, 'foo activity 1', date '2009-01-01');
insert into t2 values (2, 'bar activity 1', date '2009-01-01');
insert into t2 values (2, 'bar activity 2', date '2010-01-01');
```

Query:

```
select id, name, activity, datefield
  from (select t1.id, t1.name, t2.id as t2_id, t2.activity, t2.datefield,
               max(datefield) over (partition by t1.id) as max_datefield
          from t1
               left join t2 
                 on t1.id = t2.id
       )
 where ( (t2_id is null) or (datefield = maxdatefield) )
```

The outer where clause will filter out all but the maximum date from t2 tuples, but leave in the null row where there was no matching row in t2.

Results:

```
        ID NAME                ACTIVITY                 DATEFIELD
---------- -------- -------------------       -------------------
         1 foo           foo activity 1       2009-01-01 00:00:00
         2 bar           bar activity 2       2010-01-01 00:00:00
         3 baz
```

Answer (score 0):

To retrieve the Top N records from a query, you can use the following syntax:

```
SELECT *
FROM (your ordered by datefield desc query with join) alias_name
WHERE rownum <= 1
ORDER BY rownum;
```

PS: I am not familiar with PL/SQL so maybe I'm wrong

Comment: nope, that is not what i want. i still want to return more than 1 results in the end as i mentioned, i also join with many others tables beside table2.   but when 'right join with table2', this part i want to return 1 record with max date

Answer (score 0):

my solution is

select   from table1  right join table2  on (table1.id= table2.id and table2.datefiled= (select max(datefield) from table2 where table2.id= table1.id) )